# Module aren't found for a modified third-party package

Tags: typescript

I'm using this package `react-native-parallax-scroll-view` it doesn't have a preset types package like: `@types/...` for some reason I forced to modify this package and make my own copy now when I declare this package in `.d.ts` file like this:

`declare module "../modified_modules/react-native-parallax-scroll-view";`

it's not getting declared as a module for ts, how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure your `declare module` statement is not inside another module (i.e., there should be no top-level imports or exports in the containing `.d.ts` file) so it is treated as a module declaration rather than a module augmentation.

TypeScript does not support module declarations with relative paths; see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1720).  You should have gotten an error, "Ambient module declaration cannot specify relative module name."  If you want to import the module in your code using a relative path, the only way to provide type declarations is to put a `.d.ts` file with the appropriate top-level exports alongside the `.js` file (or virtually alongside it based on your `rootDirs` option).  As far as I know, with this approach, there is no way to declare the module as untyped (the equivalent of `declare module "../modified_modules/react-native-parallax-scroll-view";` without a body).  Thus, you'll need to set things up so you can import your module using a non-relative path and put the same non-relative path in your `declare module` statement, and then the declaration should work.

In your case, I'd suggest registering your modified module in the `package.json` of the main project by setting the version of `react-native-parallax-scroll-view` to a relative path to the directory containing the modified module.  Then `npm install` will make a symlink from `node_modules/react-native-parallax-scroll-view` to the modified module.  Since the modified module is then accessible via the standard location, this setup will hopefully cause you the least trouble.  You can just use `import ... from "react-native-parallax-scroll-view"` and `declare module "react-native-parallax-scroll-view";` as you would have used with the original module.

Answer (score 0):

> it's not getting declared as a module for ts, how can I solve this ?

Instead of

```
declare module "../modified_modules/react-native-parallax-scroll-view";
```

You [should be doing](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/migrating.html):

```
declare module "react-native-parallax-scroll-view";
```

Comment: but I use a different copy of the package If I used your solution it's going to look for this package in node_modules which is not the right location